# Oauth error no such method

Tags: google-app-engine

I don't know why, but when I launch my application I suddenly always receive the following error (that before never appeared):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.GoogleOAuthParameters.setOAuthType(Lcom/google/gdata/client/authn/oauth/OAuthParameters$OAuthType;)

The line of code generating the error is:

```
oauthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthParameters.OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH);
```

That error wasn't appeared before, always in eclipse there wasn't an error and all was working fine.

I've never changed library. It seems that when I deploy to app-engine it doesn't upload the jar with that class?

Comment: Are you saying you've deployed this application previously without seeing this error? Or have you only used it locally?

Comment: In Eclipse there aren't error and all the the import seems to be right, but when i deploy my application in the app engine i receive NoSuchMethodError exception.....Error for /initservlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.GoogleOAuthParameters.setOAuthType(Lcom/google/gdata/client/authn/oauth/OAuthParameters$OAuthType;)V
 at it.injenia.google.contactssharing.InitServlet.doGet(InitServlet.java:128) and the line 128 is that line oauthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthParameters.OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH);

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only seeing this issue when you deploy, it sounds like you've included the gdata-java-client jars in a location so that they are visible to your local Java runtime, but are not sent to the App Engine server upon deployment.

The easiest way to resolve this is to include the gdata-java-client and its dependencies in the `war/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your application, and to reference those jars in your Java build path within Eclipse.

Comment: Right now i reached the maximum frontend istance hours and the application is overquota, so i can't try until 9AM Pacific time. in the dir you told me i have these jars in build path: apps-marketplace.jars, gdata-appsforyourdomain-1.0.jar, gdata-contacts-3.0, gdata-core-1.0.jar, google_sql.jar, guava-12.jar, app engine sdk 1.6.6 and the jdk1.7.0_04....i noticed that the class OauthParameters is contained in the jars apps-marketplace.jar,gdata-core-1.0.jar...is it possibile??with the same path import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthParameters, but in diferent jars?Are there conflicts?